# Upgrading from 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) to 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, 15.04

How long does it take to upgrade from `14.10 LTS` to `15.04` ? The procedure of `Saving installed packages` is going on for last 18 hrs on my system. I have chosen the option of keeping all my personal files and packages.I am running the upgradation process by booting my system with a Live Ubuntu 15.04 disc.

Comment: You can not directly upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04, you have to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 and then to 15.04. How exactly are you upgrading 14.04 to 15.04?